# Mongoose and Node error: cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

I want to display all from my MongoDB into a table from my .ejs file. But I always get the error i wrote in my title..

Here is some code snippet:

**this is my routing js file (users.js)**

```
router.get ('/Benutzerverwaltung_Mitarbeiter', async (req, res) => {

    User.find(function (err, users) {

        // if there is an error retrieving, send the error.
        // nothing after res.send(err) will execute
        if (err)
            return res.send(err);
        res.json(users);
        res.render('Benutzerverwaltung_Mitarbeiter',{
            users: res.user
        });
    });
});
```

**and this my .ejs file:**

```
 <%- include('../routes/users.js'); %>
            <div>
                <table id="tabelle" class="cell-border"  class="table table-striped" cellspacing="0" class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>UserID</th>
                        <th>Rolle</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <% users.forEach (function (user) { %>
                    <td><%user.username%></td>
                    </tr>
                    <td><%user.admin%></td>
                    <%});%>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>
```

I hope you can help me out :)
Cheeres, Mert

Comment: Where is `res.user` coming from? Maybe you meant to do `res.user = res.json(users);` above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `res.json` and `res.render` are "terminal" methods - you should really only use them once when you are "finished", never both in the same method.

I think in this case you are trying to return html, not json, so you want `res.render`. Try this modification:

```
User.find(function (err, users) {

    // if there is an error retrieving, send the error.
    // nothing after res.send(err) will execute
    if (err)
        return res.send(err);
    res.render('Benutzerverwaltung_Mitarbeiter',{
        users: users || []
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok it worked! Thank you! But there is one problem.. I can't see the result in my table. do you know why?

Comment: The html should now be returning from this route. Whether it comes on the page would depend how you hit the route. Are you fetching it using ajax?

Comment: So, are you going to `localhost/Benutzerverwaltung_Mitarbeiter` in your browser then? One line that looks funny to me is in your ejs file: `<%- include('../routes/users.js'); %>` - I don't think you want that there. Maybe experiment with removing it. Any files you include should have more html or client scripts in them, not your node files.

Comment: yes im going through the localhost in my browser and yeah you‘re right i removed it but still doesnt work :(

Comment: This could be lots of things. But to start, you can open your dev tools and click on the network tab. Near the top you should see the request `/Benutzerverwaltung_Mitarbeiter`. You can click on it and see what was returned (use "preview" or "response") - see if you're getting an empty table, or if some other styling, etc, is hiding your content. Good luck!

Comment: Do you see the table headers? Your html table is a bit badly formed, but I'd expect you to see the headers at least.

Comment: ok my fault.. I made a mistake in my router.render function. Like you did was the right way! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In users.js, inside the res.render callback, I spot a typo when you assign the `users` property.

Array prototype functions will always throw that error above if the variable that's supposed to hold the array is not defined.

Comment: try `users: users`

Comment: now i get this error
 Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: I'm pretty sure res.json() line is conflicting with res.render().